# a/b testing gem for mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, ab-testing

exist any gem a/b testing with support for mongoid?

I have seen [split](https://github.com/andrew/split) but I don't know if have support for mongoid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/) has support for MongoDB (and Redis). It is an excellent framework, simple to set up and use, and has nice graphs.